# ping error two nic cards in linux pc

Tags: networking, rhel-6

The problem I'm having is two NIC in my RHEL 6 server with different IP-addresses.

- PC1

  - `eth0` - `10.10.0.1`
  - `eth1` - `192.168.1.1`

The other computer is setup the same way.

- PC2

  - `eth0` - `10.10.0.2`
  - `eth1` - `192.168.1.2`

All NICs are connected to a single H3C switch, no gateway or routes are defined. I am able to ping PC2 from PC1 with eth0(10.10.0.1 -- 10.10.0.2) but when i try to ping 192.168.1.2 from PC1 it returns:

```
Destination host unreachable
```

I don't want to route the traffic of `eth0` to `eth1`, is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: This is very loosely described, take your network configurations and paste them here as well as running the command "route" on both systems and pasting that here. Also you might want to actually copy paste the entire ping command as it is important as to what answered: "Destination host unreachable"

Comment: Double check ip addresses, netmasks (what netmask have you used?) and interfaces (if they are up and have link)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to ensure that the routing table is as it should be.

Both computers should have these entries:

```
10.10.0.0/16 -> eth0
192.168.1.0/24 -> eth1
```

Now, when pinging, ensure that you are binding to the correct source interface with the `-I` switch. Both of these two methods can be used:

```
ping -I 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2
ping -I eth1 192.168.1.2
```

If that doesn't work for you, you should look into setting up a metric